# How to read data from json file without using file_get_contents() and curl in PHP/Laravel?

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I have a piece of code:-

```
try{
    $jsonTechnicianData             = file_get_contents(asset('important_doc/technician_key.json'));
}
catch(\Exception $e){
    if(Globals::SHOW_EXCEPTION == 1){
        $error_message    = $e->getMessage();                       // get error message
        $error_code       = $e->getCode();                          // get error code
        $error_location   = 'Line No. ' . $e->getLine() . ' in file ' . $e->getFile();    // get error line number and file
        $error            = 'Error Code:- ' . $error_code . '| Error Message:- '. $error_message . '| Error Location:- ' . $error_location; //die;
    } else {
        $error            = 'Oops! Some error has occured.'; //die;
    }
    $technicianUrl                      = asset('important_doc/technician_key.json');
    $technicianMethod                   = Globals::CURL_GET;
    $technicianHeaderDataInfo           = array(
                                            'cache-control:no-cache',
                                            'Connection: keep-alive',
                                            'Cache-Control:no-cache',
                                            'Content-Type:application/json'
                                        );                                                  // set header
    $technicianGetArray['userAgent']    = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0";
    $technicianDataResponse             = self::apiCallViaCurl($technicianUrl, $technicianMethod, array(), $technicianHeaderDataInfo, $technicianGetArray);
    if($technicianDataResponse['status'] == true)
    {
        $jsonTechnicianData     = json_encode($technicianDataResponse['data']);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $jsonTechnicianData     = false;
    }
}
```

I am trying to first get data from the JSON file using **file_get_contents()** method. If the process fails, then I am trying to fetch the data from the JSON file using the **curl** method.

The source code is working fine in my local machine. In the first attempt, *`file_get_contents()`* is working fine.

However, in the client's server, I am facing an issue:-

This is the error message I get for *`file_get_contents()`*

```
Error Code:- 0| Error Message:- file_get_contents(): SSL: Connection reset by peer|
```

As for the curl, I am getting this error:-

```
Array
(
    [status] => 
    [data] => Array
        (
            [url] => <the url of the file>
            [content_type] => 
            [http_code] => 0
            [header_size] => 0
            [request_size] => 277
            [filetime] => -1
            [ssl_verify_result] => 0
            [redirect_count] => 0
            [total_time] => 4.024105
            [namelookup_time] => 0.013446
            [connect_time] => 0.013817
            [pretransfer_time] => 0.023667
            [size_upload] => 0
            [size_download] => 0
            [speed_download] => 0
            [speed_upload] => 0
            [download_content_length] => -1
            [upload_content_length] => 0
            [starttransfer_time] => 0
            [redirect_time] => 0
            [redirect_url] => 
            [primary_ip] => *.*.*.308
            [certinfo] => Array
                (
                )

            [primary_port] => 443
            [local_ip] => *.*.*.841
            [local_port] => 59884
        )

    [message] => Curl error: TCP connection reset by peer
    [http_code] => 0
    [url] => <the url of the file>
)
```

I have set up the curl options like this:-

```
array
(
    [CURLOPT_URL] => <the url>
    [CURLOPT_TIMEOUT] => 260
    [CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] => 1
    [CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION] => 1
    [CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] => 0
    [CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] => 0
    [CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST] => GET
    [CURLOPT_USERAGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
    [CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] => Array
        (
            [0] => cache-control:no-cache
            [1] => Connection:keep-alive
            [2] => Cache-Control:no-cache
            [3] => Content-Type:application/json
        )
)
```

Is there any other way to read the data from the JSON file?

EDIT:
The JSON file and the php file having this piece of code is in the same server.

Comment: The problem is not with your code so much as it's down to the remote machine refusing to talk to you. Finding another PHP way to read that remote file is unlikely to fix that. You need to look at the remote machine and find out why it's blocking you.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular the file I am trying to read is in the same server where my php code is.

Comment: If the file is on the same machine, why do you need to read it over a network connection? Remote or local, your problem is down to something in the network set-up.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular then cam you please suggest me a procedure regarding how to read from the json file? It would be great if you help me out.

Comment: If the file exists on your server then read it directly from the file system. If there's a good reason why you can't do that then you'll have to fix the network configuration, and that's a question beyond the scope of [so].